# Statististics Collector and Custom Reports on Apigee

Tags: apigee

I don't understand how to create a custom report based on a StatisticsCollector Policy.

I want to retrieve statistic about my API being called from different clients by checking the content of the request header called "referer".

As from the [doc](http://apigee.com/docs/analytics-services/content/analyze-api-message-content-using-custom-analytics), I created a Statistic Collector Policy, adding it to my pre-flow.

Trying to create a variable named "referer" looking at the request header "referer", I added

```
<Statistic name="referer" ref="request.header.referer" type="STRING">undefined</Statistic>
```

to the policy.

Now, as I can understand from the doc, I should found, while creating a "Custom Report", a not-better-specified "Dimension" called "referer":
"You will find that a new dimension called location is available in the UI for you to use in generating reports."

I can't find such dimension while creating a Custom Report.

I find a Custom Dimension called "name", and I have no idea where does it come from.
How am I supposed to do it? Should I try to do it by calling Apigee API?

EDIT: Apparently, the Statistic Collector does not work for free organizations on Apigee because of a "tech glitch". Srikanth from Apigee intends to open a ticket for solving this. If this is not the case, another request to update the documentation on Apigee, stating that the Collector does not work for free org, will be raised by Archendra Yadav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the few things to note.

1. Browsers are very careful about Referer headers. They do not send it even if you set them. Even Postman client on chrome does not send the Referer header when specified. This is a valid security gate - HTTP 1.1 RFC talks about it. You can read about the same behaviour in other places on web.
2. So as Divya mentioned use curl request. Use the trace session to figure out what was the original request received by Edge from client. This way you figure out the existence of the referer header. You will see that its missing when sent from browser manually. Curl works fine.
3. Are you using a free org or paid org on Apigee. The statistic collector fails to work on the free org at times. I had a chat with an internal expert who gave me this insight.

Comment: The headers parameters are present, I'm using Restclient to make the calls, and I can see the data using Apigee tracer. I'm on free org, so you are saying that for the free org the statistic collector does not work. Good to know. It would be a nice idea to write this on the documentation...

Comment: Can you give me your org name. I will try workout internal suggestions for your org.

Comment: I intend to raise a support ticket for your case. To be more clear -  Its because of tech glitch than feature unavailability - hence not a candidate for documentation.

Comment: Thanks Srikanth, my org name is FACEIT

Answer (score 1):

Emas -- Thanks for the suggestion. I'll raise a request with documentation team to update the documentation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The field referer will be added under Drilldown --> Custom Dimensions after you send some requests to the API where yyou have added the below statics collector policy.This policy needs to be executed once to add the new field to the Custom dimension

Comment: Thanks rpattnaik for the reply. I did exactly what you wrote - but it doesn't work. I stared a traced session, I made some calls, I can see the request header being processed in the pipeline, my request goes throught the statistic collector, but I cannot see the header parameter under "Custom Dimensions". It would be very helpful if somebody from Apigee would look at my configuration to check if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are using the following:

```
<Statistic name="referer" ref="request.header.referer" type="STRING">undefined</Statistic>
```

I believe the type is case sensitive. Try type="string" and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that snippet was generated automatically by Apigee after I used the UI for inserting the Collector. I changed from STRING to string, no luck .. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The request header name is 'Referer' and not 'referer'.

So, your StatisticsCollector policy should look something like this :

StatisticsCollector-1
    
    
    
        request.header.Referer

Try some calls and make sure the request has a header named Referer. Then it would come up as a Custom Dimension in your custom report.
For me I had to explicitly mention the Referer header in my request like this :

curl -v "https://product-support-test.apigee.net/" -H "Referer: foo"

Please send me your bundle if you still face issues(divya@apigee.com).

Comment: HTTP Headers are case-insensitive hence "Referer' or 'referer' does not matter.

Comment: I tried also with a "foo-referer" header parameter, no way. I'm using a free org, so the reason as Srikanth wrote is that the statistic collector does not work.